# Fastest way of querying and filtering pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes which are read from 2 existing spreadsheets:
The first one (df_summary) looks like this

| Unique_ID | Age | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19 | Paul | Smith |
| 2 | 22 | Chris | Lorne |

The second one (df_mass) looks like

| Unique_ID | Time | Mass |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 62.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 62.3 |
| 1 | 3 | 63.1 |
| 1 | 4 | 63.4 |
| 2 | 1 | 72.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 71.2 |
| 2 | 3 | 71.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 71.7 |
| 2 | 5 | 70.8 |

Showing the mass of people at different points in time. I would like to query df_mass to find the last recorded mass and add it to df_summary.
At the moment I have it working like:

```
for unique_ID in df_summary['Unique_ID']:
        data = df_mass [df_mass ['Unique_ID'] == unique_ID]
        df_summary.loc[df_summary['Unique_ID'] == unique_ID, 'Final Mass'] = data['Mass'].tolist()[-1]
```

Which works but isn't very elegant and is quite slow when I have many participants and many time points for each.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_mass.sort_values(by='Time', ascending=True, inplace=True)['Mass']
data = df_mass.groupby('Unique_ID').agg({'Time': 'last', 'Mass': 'last'})
df_summary = df_summary.merge(data, on='Unique_ID', copy=False, how='left')
df_summary.rename({'Mass': 'Final Mass'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby_apply`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2.groupby('Unique_ID')
                 .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Time'].idxmax(), 'Mass'])
                 .rename('Final Mass').reset_index(), how='left')

   Unique_ID  Age   Name Surname  Final Mass
0          1   19   Paul   Smith        63.4
1          2   22  Chris   Lorne        70.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

Optionally sort `df_mass` by `Unique_ID` and `Time` if not already in this order

```
df_mass = df_mass.sort_values(['Unique_ID', 'Time'])
```

**Step 1:** Create a `df_Final_Mass`  dataframe by aggregating the ***last entry of `Mass` per `Unique_ID`*** by [`GroupBy.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df_Final_Mass = df_mass.groupby('Unique_ID')['Mass'].last().reset_index(name='Final Mass')


   Unique_ID  Final Mass
0          1        63.4
1          2        70.8
```

**Step 2:** Merge `df_summary` with `df_Final_Mass` on same `Unique_ID`:

```
df_final = df_summary.merge(df_Final_Mass, on='Unique_ID', how='left')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_final)


   Unique_ID  Age   Name Surname  Final Mass
0          1   19   Paul   Smith        63.4
1          2   22  Chris   Lorne        70.8
```